# wysihtml5 commands come up as undefined

Tags: javascript, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

When I load up the `wysithml5` bootstrap editor, this command or any command that `wysihtml5` bootstrap supports does not work.

When I alert `editor.composer.commands`, it comes up as undefined.

What can I do to fix this? jQuery is loaded with jQuery-UI, I don't know if that helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').wysihtml5();
    var editor = $('#content').wysihtml5().data("wysihtml5").editor;
    editor.currentView.element.focus();
    editor.composer.commands.exec('insertHTML' , 'Something');`
});
```

Referenced editor: https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5

Comment: here are my libraries js/wysihtml5-0.3.0_rc1.min.js"></script>     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: well then i have no idea. You are going to have a lot of trouble finding somebody with experience on this editor I think. And what editor, has you pulling data from it? Very confusing....

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Having the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when programmatically using commands soon after the editor is instantiated and loaded to the page. Consider the following code:

```
<textarea id="wysihtml5-textarea" rows="3" autofocus></textarea>
```

I solved it by allowing some time after the editor is loaded using window.setTimeout. The code below is an example using 'insertImage' command:

```
$(function () {
   var editorEle = $('#wysihtml5-textarea');
   var editorToolbarEle = $('#wysihtml5-toolbar');
   var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor(editorEle.prop('id'), {});

   window.setTimeout(function() {
      editor.focus();
      editor.composer.commands.exec("insertImage", { src: 'foo.png', alt: "image.." });
   }, 200);
});
```

You can see this code running and test it using the following JSFiddle (remove the setTimeout to see the error occur):

http://jsfiddle.net/wv0fbsew/

I had this problem when using a forked version of the editor (wysihtml5x). It is not the Bootstrap version mentioned on this question, neither the one I was using, but the issue is the same.